# How can I pass custom set data to a src image "onClick"?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have this function

```
 function changeImage() {
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-image-path'));
        document.getElementById('image-id').src = event.target.getAttribute('data-image-path');
    }
```

on click I want to pass the `data-image-path` into the `changeImage` function, the `data-image-path` is inside the `li` so is the onclick:

```
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png" onclick='changeImage(this.data-image-path)'> 
<div class="inside-li">
<img src="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/feat1.png" alt="image"> 
<p>Easy Scheduling &amp; Attendance Tracking</p>
</div>
<div class="plan-hr">
   <hr class="hr-1">
   <hr class="hr-2">
</div>
</li>
```

image:[image: li image]

I have multiple `li` elements and each contains a different `src` image inside its `data-image-path` but how can I pass the data?

This is the `img` element that should recieve the `src`:

```
<div class="image-loader col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="banner-thumb-wrap">
       <div class="banner-thumb">
          <img class="header-inner-img" id="image-id">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the result in my console.log and code:
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, pass `this` to `changeImage` function and get the attribute of the clicked element.

```
function changeImage(obj) {
        var imagePath2 = obj.getAttribute('data-image-path');
        document.getElementById('image-id').src = imagePath2;
    }

<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png" onclick='changeImage(this)'> </li>
```

Comment: This woks! thanks a lot, many of the other suggestions were returning null but this made my code fully run. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that @RandomCoder

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.target.getAttribute('data-image-path')` to get the clicked `li`'s `data-image-path` value inside `changeImage()` method.

```js
function changeImage() {
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-image-path'));
  document.getElementById('image-id').src = event.target.getAttribute('data-image-path');
}
```

```html
<img class="header-inner-img" id="image-id">

<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png" onclick='changeImage()'> </li>
```

Comment: This method is returning a "null" src image, what could possibly be causing the error?

Comment: not sure what you mean, run the above code snippet. you can see the data-image-path value when you click the li tag

Comment: Most of the methods I am recieving seem to be working on the snippet, but whenevr I try it inside my project it returns "null" for some reason

Comment: can you update your question with your whole codebase?

Comment: where is the tag that has the id of image-id ? can you attach the whole codebase using code snippet?

Comment: The codebase is too big, I have added the img element just above the console image, it is inside <div class="banner-thumb">
          <img class="header-inner-img" id="image-id">
       </div>

Comment: what is console log result inside changeImage()?

Comment: I have added an image, isnt the result showing? But as in my reference code which I used your suggested code I am getting a null result in my console.log and no src path + an error "null:1 GET file:///C:/Users/WinDows/Desktop/El-saturn/null net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" but when I seem to aedit the src="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png' the image does appear

Answer (score 2):

You can change your HTML into this:

```
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png" onclick='changeImage(event.target.dataset.imagePath)'> </li>
```

But there is a better version:

Select the `li` elements with `querySelectorAll` and `addEventListener` for them afterward.

Comment: src image was returned "undefined" with this method

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dawn-nsg1j?file=/index.html


There's a working version here, please check it out...?
It's working on my trial...!

Comment: I just updated my code for reference, most of the solutions I got seem to be working. But for some reason in my project I recieve a null src

Answer (score 2):

I slightly changed your html code, and significantly changed the js code using the `forEach` method, with a `click` listener inside. This means that calling the `onclick=changeImage (this.data-image-path)` event is no longer needed! I also left the `console` so that you can see which attribute is being loaded on click at the moment.

I hope that is exactly what you needed.

```js
var li_attr = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var img = document.getElementById('image-id');
        
Array.from(li_attr).forEach(function(li_attrArray, i) {
    li_attrArray.addEventListener('click', function() {
    imagePath2 = li_attrArray.getAttribute('data-image-path');
    img.src = imagePath2;

    console.log(img.src);
  });
});
```

```html
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc1.png">1</li>
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png">2</li>
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc3.png">3</li>
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc4.png">4</li>

<img class="header-inner-img" id="image-id">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the event and then access the data through the `event.target.getAttribute()`

```js
function changeImage(e) {
  const dataImagePath = e.target.getAttribute('data-image-path');
  document.getElementById('image-id').src = dataImagePath;
  console.log(dataImagePath);
  console.log(document.getElementById('image-id').src);
}
```

```html
<li data-image-path="./assets/img/my_imgs/features/sc2.png" onclick='changeImage(event)'> </li>
<img class="header-inner-img" id="image-id">
```

Comment: Recieved a "null" result in my code, I have updated the reference code with another suggested answer but i get the same error as in this suggestion